# get Date without time in java

Tags: java, java.util.date, date

I want to get a Date without time, but always failed.
below is my codes:

```
    long curLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
    curLong = curLong -  curLong % TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
    Date date = new Date(curLong);
    System.out.println("date = " + date);
```

the output:

```
date = Mon Oct 28 08:00:00 CST 2019
```

anyone knows why? Thank you

Comment: Because `java.util.Date` represents an instant in time. You should use the `java.time` API instead, such as `LocalDate`.

Comment: How about `LocalDate.now()`?

Comment: General advice: Don't use `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and all the related classes. Ignore all StackOverflow or internet advice that tells you to use them. Use only the `java.time` classes, and only tolerate the above classes in legacy code.

Comment: What you've written ought to get midnight GMT. I don't know why that would convert to 8 AM CST. That doesn't seem to add up right.

Comment: @khelwood 00:00t in GMT agrees with 08:00 China Standard Time, so this is probably what CST stands for in this case. The question was also posted from Nanjing, China. Those d*rn ambiguous time zone abbreviations…

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for resolving the mystery.

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to use `java.util.Date` anymore. It was called `Date` but doesn't necessarily hold only the date information but information about the time additionally.

Use this:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
```

and print it as

```
System.out.println(today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
```

using the ISO date format. You can define your own formatting pattern using a

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

for example.

Comment: Any notable difference between using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE` and and just `toString()`?

Comment: @Glains I think [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) will give an output *in the ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd*, while [`ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE) will put an offset if available. Otherwise there is no obvious or documented difference I could find for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `java.time.LocalDate.now()` to get just the date.

Anyway, your case doesn't work as you expect because you are doing nothing to remove the time from the date: you are just "repressing" it, that's why it's zero. If you want to continue this way you could always `substring` it (substring the `Date.toString()` of course I meant).

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.Date`'s javadoc states:

> The class `Date` represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

Thats why you have date with time

If you want a date you can use : `java.time.LocalDate.now()` (Java 8+)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, stop using the old `java.util.Date`. The new Java 8 date and time API has much better classes for all date and time operations.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class does exactly what you want. 
The current date can be obtained by `LocalDate.now()`.

It also has a lot of facilities to add and subtract days, months etc. and it takes into consideration all the calendar special cases for you.